# In BigQuery SQL, how to replace a category name by another if how much this category represents in the total table is below a specific threshold

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sorry if the title is not well written, but I didn't think of any way better to phrase it.

I have a table similar to the following one and I am using it in BigQuery:

[image]

I can check how much each `failure_reason` represents of all the failed `status`:

[image]

I want to create a new table in which all the `failure_reason` that have 10% or less of the total failed `status` are replaced by the value `other`. In the end, my table would look like this:

[image]

How can I do this? I am trying to use a window with a partition by, but it doesn't work. The best that I have been able to build so far is the following:

```
with
mytable as (
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST([
      STRUCT("2022-08-01" AS month, "successful" AS status, "" as failure_reason, 1000 as qty),            
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason A", 550),
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason B", 300),
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason C", 100),
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason D", 50),
            ("2022-09-01","successful", "", 1500),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason A", 800),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason B", 110),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason C", 80),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason D", 10),
            ("2022-10-01","successful", "", 1100),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason A", 600),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason B", 210),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason C", 120),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason D", 50),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason E", 20) ])
),

mytable_share as ( 
select
    failure_reason,
    (sum(qty) / (sum(qty) over (partition by status))) as share
from
  mytable
where
  status = "failed"
group by
  failure_reason
)

select 
  month,
  status,
  case when share <= 0.1 then "other"
       else failure_reason
       end as failure_reason,
  qty
  from
    mytable
  left join
    mytable_share
  using (failure_reason)
order by
  1,
  2,
  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated this to use `window functions` because it reads cleaner.

```
with cte as
(select *, sum(quantity) over (partition by status,failure_reason)/sum(quantity) over(partition by status) as share
 from my_table)

select month,
       status,
       case when status='failed' and share<=0.1 then 'other' else failure_reason end, 
       sum(quantity) as qty
from cte
group by month,
         status, 
         case when status='failed' and share<=0.1 then 'other' else failure_reason end
```

Answer (score 0):

At least, in my system the following works, but there might be problems in other systems because the GROUP BY clauses within the parentheses have more columns in the SELECT part than in the GROUP BY. In these cases my SQL-system triggers an automatic remerging that is necessary here. So, if you have problems then you have to insert one more step in each parentheses group to merge "manually".

Besides, please note that I renamed "successful" to "0_successful" and "other" to "x_other" so that the rows are in the correct order when using UNION CORRESPONDING.
Otherwise, the sorting will be different, e.g. the "failed" rows will then be positioned before the "successful" rows.

```
select month,
       "0_successful" as status,
       failure_reason,
       quantity
from test
where status = "successful"
union corresponding
select month,
       status,
       failure_reason,
       quantity
from 
(select month, status, failure_reason, 
       quantity 
 from test
 where status = "failed"
 group by failure_reason
 having (sum(quantity)/(select sum(quantity) from test where status = "failed"))
         >0.1
 )
union corresponding
select month,
       status,
       "x_other" as failure_reason,
       sum(quantity) as quantity
from 
(select month, status, failure_reason, 
       quantity 
 from test
 where status = "failed"
 group by failure_reason
 having (sum(quantity)/(select sum(quantity) from test where status = "failed"))
         <=0.1
 )
 group by month, status, calculated failure_reason
```

Here is my result:

```
month      | status    | failure_reason | quantity
-----------|-----------|----------------|-----------
2022-08-01 | 0_success |                | 1000
2022-08-01 | failed    | reason A       | 550
2022-08-01 | failed    | reason B       | 300
2022-08-01 | failed    | x_other        | 150
2022-09-01 | 0_success |                | 1500
2022-09-01 | failed    | reason A       | 800
2022-09-01 | failed    | reason B       | 110
2022-09-01 | failed    | x_other        | 90
2022-10-01 | 0_success |                | 1500
2022-10-01 | failed    | reason A       | 600
2022-10-01 | failed    | reason B       | 210
2022-10-01 | failed    | x_other        | 190
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses two CTE's: One to calculate the fail sum per reason, and the second to determine which reasons you don't want to group into "other".

```
with my_table as (
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST([
      STRUCT("2022-08-01" AS month, "successful" AS status, "" as failure_reason, 1000 as quantity),            
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason A", 550),
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason B", 300),
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason C", 100),
            ("2022-08-01","failed", "reason D", 50),
            ("2022-09-01","successful", "", 1500),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason A", 800),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason B", 110),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason C", 80),
            ("2022-09-01","failed", "reason D", 10),
            ("2022-10-01","successful", "", 1100),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason A", 600),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason B", 210),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason C", 120),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason D", 50),
            ("2022-10-01","failed", "reason E", 20) ])
),
reason_totals as (
  select failure_reason, sum(quantity) as total_fail
  from my_table
  where status = 'failed'
  group by rollup(failure_reason)
), 
reasons_to_include as (
  select failure_reason
  from reason_totals
  where total_fail / (select total_fail from reason_totals where failure_reason is null) > 0.1
  and failure_reason is not null
)
select t.month, t.status, 
 case
  when t.status = 'successful' then ''
  else coalesce(r.failure_reason, 'other') 
 end failure_reason, 
sum(t.quantity) as quantity
from my_table t 
left join reasons_to_include r 
  on t.failure_reason = r.failure_reason
group by 1,2,3;
```

Output:

| month | status | failure_reason | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | successful |  | 1000 |
| 2022-08-01 | failed | reason A | 550 |
| 2022-08-01 | failed | reason B | 300 |
| 2022-08-01 | failed | other | 150 |
| 2022-09-01 | successful |  | 1500 |
| 2022-09-01 | failed | reason A | 800 |
| 2022-09-01 | failed | reason B | 110 |
| 2022-09-01 | failed | other | 90 |
| 2022-10-01 | successful |  | 1100 |
| 2022-10-01 | failed | reason A | 600 |
| 2022-10-01 | failed | reason B | 210 |
| 2022-10-01 | failed | other | 190 |

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to group/partition by `month` and `failure_reason` based on your desired outcome.

Secondly, when joining `mytable` on `mytable_share` we need to make sure that we join on `month` AND `failure_reason`.

Finally, we need to summarize qty for "other" `failure_reason` as we can have multiple rows related to that.

```
mytable_share as ( 
select
    month,
    failure_reason,
    (sum(qty) * 1.0 / (sum(qty) over (partition by month, status))) as share
from
  mytable
where
  status = "failed"
group by
  failure_reason, month
)

select 
  mytable.month,
  mytable.status,
  case when mytable_share.share <= 0.1 then "other"
       else mytable.failure_reason
       end as failure_reason,
  SUM(qty) qty
  from
    mytable
  left join
    mytable_share
  ON mytable.month = mytable_share.month
  AND COALESCE(mytable.failure_reason, "") = COALESCE(mytable_share.failure_reason, "")
group by
  1,
  2,
  3
order by
  1,
  2,
  3
```